# How to add the employer organisation including custom field to the event enrollment form

Tags: civievent, profile

Currently I do a project for an organisation that organizes events for employees in a certain industry. When a person enrolls in an event they want to record a number of his employer like:

- the address.
- a category of the organisation.
- a VAT number
- etc..

I know how to this with Drupal forms, but unfortunately they do not use it. So I tried it with profiles in combination with the native event page. I can add fields of the participant, and the contact. What I cannot do is add organisation fields.

Does someone know (or created) and extension, that makes it possible to add an organisation profile to an event form. When the form is filled in the organisation is created and subsequently to the participant with employer relationship.